# PostgresSQL created a user account on OSX

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, database, postgresql

Hello I installed PostgresSQL on my macbook but when I restarted my macbook later I saw that instead of the usual User account and the Guest account I now have also a Postgres user in my startup page of OSX.. My question is: Can I delete this safely without ruining Postgres and **how** do I delete this safely?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at all surprised that a user was created, but I'm a little surprised it shows up in the control panel. Actually, several apps create their own users, but usually they are invisible to the regular MacOS.

Unless it causes a specific problem, I'd leave it.

Comment: I have deleted the account but my Postgres seems to work tough.. It was just that it annoyed me on startup :)

Comment: I can verify this is annoying.